# The inverse of a natural isomorphism is a natural isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

Let $F,G:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ be functors and let $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$ be a natural transformation between them. Suppose that, for every object $C\in\mathcal{C}$, the morphism $\alpha_C:FC\to GC$ is an isomorphism, and let $\beta_C:GC\to FC$ be its inverse. I want to prove that $\beta=(\beta_C:GC\to FC)_{C\in\mathcal{C}}$ is a natural transformation. To do that, for every morphism $h:C\to C'$ in $\mathcal{C}$, I need to show that $Fh\circ \beta_C=\beta_{C'}\circ Gh$. What I know is that $Gh\circ\alpha_C=\alpha_{C'}\circ Fh$.

Can you give some help please?

Comment: Please, please, stop appropriating the name and face of a celebrated and recently deceased mathematician. It's in terrible taste.

Comment: Maybe it is better to specify natural isomorphism in the title, in general components of natural transformations need not be invertible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the naturality relation and the fact that $\alpha^{-1}=\beta.$ That is,

$\alpha_{C'}\circ Fh\circ \beta_C=Gh\circ\alpha_C\circ\beta_C=Gh\circ1_C=Gh\Rightarrow Fh\circ \beta_C=\beta_{C'}\circ Gh$

Comment: Has this *inverse* some value in the development of category theory?