# Why are natural isomorphisms injective on objects?

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

[Here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+isomorphism), [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657046/the-inverse-of-a-natural-isomorphism-is-a-natural-isomorphism) says a natural isomorphism $\eta \colon F \rightarrow G$ can be regarded as a natural transformation with a two sided inverse, or alternatively each $\eta_X$ is an isomorphism. But what if $G$ isn’t one-to-one on the objects so two inverses are associated to some $G(X)$?

Comment: Why do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: Because the "inverse" of $\eta$ wouldn't be a function on the objects. So it wouldn't be a natural transformation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But what if $G$ isn’t one-to-one on the objects so two inverses are associated to some $G(X)$?

The inverse of $η_X \colon F(X) \to G(X)$ is not associated to $G(X)$, but to $X$.

Suppose that $F, G \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$.
The natural transformation $η$ consists of components $η_X \colon F(X) \to G(X)$, and these components are indexed by the objects $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$, *not* the  objects $F(X)$ or $G(X)$ of $\mathcal{D}$.
The natural transformation $η^{-1}$ consists similarly of components $(η^{-1})_X \colon G(X) \to F(X)$, and once again these components are indexed by the objects $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$, *not* the objects $G(X)$ or $F(X)$ of $\mathcal{D}$.